# Components in Delegates in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I wonder about the impact of having a component in a delegate of a `ListView`

Consider this:

*DelegatePrototype.qml*

```
MouseArea {
    property Component myPage
    onClicked: { 
        myPageLoader.sourceComponent = myPage
        myPageLoader.pageData = model
    }
}
```

and *main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    width: 1024
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Loader {
        id: myPageLoader
        x: 100
        active: true
        property var pageData
    }

    Component {
        id: myDelegate
        DelegatePrototype {
            width: 100
            height: 50
            myPage: Rectangle {
                width: 400
                height: 800
                color: 'steelblue'
                Column {
                    Text {
                        text: pageData.name
                    }
                    Row {
                        spacing: 4
                        Repeater {
                            model: pageData.age
                            delegate: Rectangle {
                                color: 'red'
                                width: 7
                                height: 30
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: model.name
            }
        }
    }


    ListView {
        width: 100
        height: 800
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { name: 'Herbert'; age: 5 }
            ListElement { name: 'Hans'; age: 3 }
            ListElement { name: 'Ludwig'; age: 12 }
            ListElement { name: 'Franz'; age: 9 }
            ListElement { name: 'Peter'; age: 2 }
            ListElement { name: 'Karl'; age: 15 }
        }

        delegate: myDelegate
    }
}
```

So for the question: I have the `property Component myPage` in the `DelegatePrototype` and in `main.qml` I assign a component to it, that I declare *on-the-fly*.
I might have instead explicitly declared a component beforehand, and assigned it then like this:

```
Component {
    id: myPageDelegate
    Rectangle {
        width: 400
        height: 800
        color: 'steelblue'
        Column {
            Text {
                text: pageData.name
            }
            Row {
                spacing: 4
                Repeater {
                    model: pageData.age
                    delegate: Rectangle {
                        color: 'red'
                        width: 7
                        height: 30
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Component {
    id: myDelegate
    DelegatePrototype {
        width: 100
        height: 50
        myPage: myPageDelegate
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: model.name
        }
    }
}
```

While I belive in the latter case, I have only one `Component`-object for `myPage` in my memory, and for each of the instantiated `DelegatePrototype`s only a reference to this, I might imagine that in the former case it might happen that I create a `Component`-Object for `myPage` for each instance of `DelegatePrototype`, which might clutter the memory with identical `Component`-objects pretty fast.

Is my assumption right here and I should avoid assigning those *on-the-fly*-declarations of `Components` or will QML optimize this for me?

---

I know, there are crossfile-references (myPageLoader is referenced from the DelegatePrototype) but for the question I don't think it is necessary to explain why I chose to use this crossfile-reference.